# Issue with mod rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess

I have rewrite rules in a htaccess file working perfectly except for one weird issue that is not redirecting to the index.php like it should.

apache2 running on Debian

site.com/abc/xyz processes through site.com/index.php like it should

site.com/somethingelse/folderx/1234 processes through site.com/index.php like it should

site.com/accounts/ processes through site.com/index.php like it should
BUT
site.com/accounts/orders/1234 processes straight to site.com/accounts/orders.php without going to root/index.php like it is supposed to.

rewrite rules in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule \. - [L]
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Is there a simple reason that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you have `Multiviews` turned on. It's part of content negotiation and can cause apache to do unexpected stuff like what you're describing with `/orders/` -> `/orders.php`. Try turning it off:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteRule \. - [L]
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. That was it. I could have saved a lot of wasted work if I had asked here sooner.